# css max height on parent with overflow on child

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, grid

How to make `.col` element 100% of `.container`?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  gap: 10px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(189, 66, 66, 0.226);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMJq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
align-items: start;
```

On your `.container` element. I am not expert especially with these max-height and overflow, but it seems to make the deal.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(189, 66, 66, 0.226);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to go full width and put the Elements under each user simply give the Container "flex-direction: column;"

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(189, 66, 66, 0.226);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know how this got upvoted - it's got rid of the two column layout

Comment: container needs to be row direction

Comment: Ok sorry to hear that. I don't really get what you are trying to do. Do you want it to be 100% width or 100% height?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete), simple wrapping `.container` with div without flx is working.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.overflow-wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(189, 66, 66, 0.226);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overflow-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```